# how to accsses to getSupportFragmentManager from static method?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I'm using RecyclerView to show data. Inside the recycler view i have method onClick and i want to replace between fragments. The only problem i have is that i can not accsses to getSupportFragmentManager or getChildFragmentManager from static method.
The RecyclerView is inside a fragment and not activity.

**This is the RecyclerView code**

```
 public static class TypeMusicListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TypeMusicListViewHolder>{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> data;

    public TypeMusicListAdapter(Context context, List<String> data){
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeMusicListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type_music_item,parent,false);
        return new TypeMusicListViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TypeMusicListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String songType = data.get(position);
        //holder.musicType.setText(songType.getSongName());
        holder.musicType.setText(songType);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}

public static class TypeMusicListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView musicType;
    private FragmentManager fm;


    public TypeMusicListViewHolder(View itemView,FragmentManager fm) {
        super(itemView);
        musicType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.musicType);
        this.fm = fm;
        musicType.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().
                beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.container, new GenresFragment()).
                commit();
    }
}
```

Gives me error in the getSupportFragmentManager ofcourse...
What should i do..?

Answer (score 1):

Change your view holder class so that it has a member variable for your activity.

```
public static class TypeMusicListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView musicType;
    private FragmentManager fm;
AppCompatActivity activity;

    public TypeMusicListViewHolder(View itemView,FragmentManager fm,AppCompatActivity act) {
        super(itemView);
        musicType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.musicType);
        this.fm = fm;
activity = act;
        musicType.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().
                beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.container, new GenresFragment()).
                commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How should i initialize the AppCompatActivity when i bring it outside from the Recycler. Btw its in Fragment and not Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback interface.

**CALLBACK CLASS**

```
public interface MyCallback{

  void onButtonClick();
}
```

**ADAPTER**

```
 public static class TypeMusicListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TypeMusicListViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private List<String> data;

public TypeMusicListAdapter(Context context, List<String> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public TypeMusicListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type_music_item,parent,false);
    return new TypeMusicListViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TypeMusicListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String songType = data.get(position);
    //holder.musicType.setText(songType.getSongName());
    holder.musicType.setText(songType);

    holder.musicType.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    ((YourActivity) context).onButtonClick();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
}

   public static class TypeMusicListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private TextView musicType;
private FragmentManager fm;


public TypeMusicListViewHolder(View itemView,FragmentManager fm) {
    super(itemView);
    musicType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.musicType);
    this.fm = fm;
}


}
```

**YOUR ACTIVITY / FRAGMENT**

```
(...)

void onButtonClick(){
     getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.container, new GenresFragment()).
            commit();
}
```